# how do I display the alternating icons in editText?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

so I have editText with closes and success icons and maximum password 6, the first thing I do is if the password is not maximum 6, the icon remains closes like I drew, if the password is maximum 6 then the closes icon changes to the success icon, my problem how to change the closes icon to a success icon if the maximum 6 conditions are met

[image: editTest image]

**this is my code**

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputPassword"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:hint="Password"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    app:counterMaxLength="6"
    app:endIconMode="clear_text"
    app:endIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_canceles"
    app:errorEnabled="true"
    app:endIconTint="#DF0000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputEmail">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your on create method

```
TextInputLayout editText = findViewById(R.id.textInputPassword);


                editText.getEditText().addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        if (s.toString().length() > 6) {
                            editText.setEndIconDrawable(R.drawable.success);
                        } else {
                            editText.setEndIconDrawable(R.drawable.ic_canceles);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: i will try it @NattoShaw

Comment: error code in kotlin, Unresolved reference: activity_sign_in_with_email ->  @NattoShaw

Comment: Could I possibly see a screenshot please?

Comment: You need to put the code outside the submit button click listener

Comment: ok i have done it and if it is updated then hide icon before retyping, i include the video -> https://ibb.co/vwDG3hx @NattoShaw

Comment: i use -> setErrorIconDrawable

Comment: Type textinputPassword.setErrorEnabled(true); in the on text change method

Comment: it can't be the same, if you press again on the textview it will hiden and tapil if typed, like the view that I uploaded @NattoShaw

Comment: Ok I think I know what the problem is, try doing this instead,
In your on text changed type in:
```
if (s.toString() > 6){
textInputPassword.endIconMode = TextInputLayout.END_ICON_CUSTOM; textInputPassword.endIconDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_success);
} else {
textInputPassword.endIconMode = TextInputLayout.END_ICON_CUSTOM; textInputPassword.endIconDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_canceless);
}
```

Comment: ok, better than before, thank you, for helping me, may I ask one more time and can you help me? @NattoShaw

Comment: I want to make validation to display regular expression characters, if it doesn't add the regex icon it still fails, when added it will be a success, how to make it @NattoShaw

Comment: Try creating a method returning boolean and has a string paramter, check for its length and check for characters like so: public boolean isValid(String s) {
 Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[$&+,:;=\\\\?@#|/'<>.^*()%!-]");

 if (regex.matcher(s).find() && s.length() > 6) {
        return true;
 }
return false;
}

Then on the text changed type in

if (isValid(s.toString())) {
 editText.setEndIconDrawable(R.drawable.success);
} else {
 editText.setEndIconDrawable(R.drawable.ic_canceles);
}

Comment: The method isValid should be out side like the onCreate method

Comment: The code should be:fun isValid(s: String) : Boolean {
    val regex = Pattern.compile("[$&+,:;=\\\\?@#|/'<>.^*()%!-]']")
 if (regex.matcher(s).find() && s.length > 6) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

Comment: Then in your onTextchanged method type in: if (isValid(s.toString())) {
    textInputPassword.setEndIconDrawable(R.drawable.ic_success)
} else {
    textInputPassword.setEndIconDrawable(R.drawable.ic_canceles)
}

Comment: I've made it and it works, but I gave a limit of 6, if passing from 6, the success icon still appears and I want to make it if more than 6 then display the closes icon, I've tried it with a statement like this does not work, I have a problem other than using regex but if I enter code other than uppercase letters, lowercase letters and numbers will produce a successful icon, if I add _ * # $ this will produce a successful icon, this is code me -> https://pastebin.com/mNAxyShY

Comment: You're not putting it in the listener it should be exactly like this ->https://pastebin.com/FR6CXQVs

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
         textInputPassword.seticon(R.drawable.image);
```

Comment: I put it on the statement to change the icon, I want without I press the button, the icon automatically changes @Shimaa Yasser